# MailChimp API subscribe in PHP

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm incredibly rusty but trying to change the email product used on a website. I've been reading through some previously answered questions and have the below code.

The page is progressing, adding the user to the site database but not the MailChimp list. Where am I falling down?

```
$apikey = 'api key-us16';
$auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );

$data = array(
    'apikey'        => $apikey,
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
        'FNAME' => $firstname
    )
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/mylistid/members/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                            'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);   


//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: And what's the result of your request? Can you make a `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: I really am learning as I go here. I have added 
    echo "<pre>" . var_dump($result) . "</pre>";
to the bottom of the function but the next page doesn't show anything